# How to "hide" superclass methods in a subclass

Tags: python, attributes, properties, subclass

I basically want to create a subclass that "hides" methods on the superclass so that they don't show up in a `dir()` or `hasattr()` call and the users can't call them (at least not through any of the normal channels).  I would also like to do this with the least amount of "magic" possible.  Thanks.

Comment: "can't call them"?  Isn't that the same as "does nothing useful"?  Or is that the same as "raises an exception"?

Comment: It's part of a home-rolled db ORM I'm using.  The auto-generated python objects allow access to modify all database fields, but I'd like to have more control over some fields and not allow the user to modify them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overriding the `__dir__` and `__getattribute__` method respectively should do the trick. This is the pretty much the canonical way to do this kind of stuff in Python. Although whether you should be actually doing this is entirely a different matter.

See Python docs on [Customizing Attribute Access](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access)

**Use `__dir__` to list available attributes** (this won't affect actual attribute access)

```
class A(object):
    def __dir__(self):
        return []

>>> print dir(A())
[]
```

**Use `__getattribute__` to control actual attribute access**

```
class A(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        """Prevent 'private' attribute access"""
        if attr.startswith('_'):
            raise AttributeError

        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)


>>> a = A()
>>> a.x = 5
>>> a.x
5
>>> a._x = 3
>>> a._x
AttributeError
```

This is probably what you are trying to do.

```
class NoSuper(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        """Prevent accessing inherited attributes"""
        for base in self.__bases__:
            if hasattr(base, attr):
                raise AttributeError

        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Though the `__dir__` method trick doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `__dir__` method is supposed to just return a list of attributes, it doesn't actually control object attribute access. Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Ah, the __dir__ method is python2.6+ only.

Answer (score 6):

You should not subclass then, you should use composition. Wrap your other class instance in a new class instance and use as necessary.