# How can I "undefine" Python magic methods on a subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, liskov-substitution-principle, python-datamodel

Is there a way in Python 3 to indicate that a class does not support some operation that its parent class supports?*  I know that classes can set `__hash__` to `None` to indicate a type is unhashable, but this doesn't seem to work in general.

For example, let's suppose I have some collection class with a `__len__` method, and I want to make a child class representing an unbounded collection that has no defined size.  If I set `__len__` to `None` in the subclass I get an ugly/confusing error message when I try to get the length of the collection.

```
>>> class C:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 3
... 
>>> class D(C):
...     __len__ = None
... 
>>> len(D())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I would like to get an error as if `D` did not define `__len__` at all:

```
>>> class E:
...     pass
...
>>> len(E())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'E' has no len()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827277/) is related, however my question pertains specifically to magic methods / operator overloading.  Since Python magic methods are looked up directly on the object's type, some possible approaches like overriding `__getattribute__` or using descriptors would not work here.

*Note: I know this would violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), but if I wanted type safety I wouldn't be using Python in the first place.  ;)

Comment: Why not `raise NotImplementedError` from the child? Also note that dynamic typing is not the same as creating a broken class structure; could you give some context as to why you think you need this?

Answer (score 1):

I would not be looking to "undefine" it since that just might make it more confusing. I'd be explicit and tailor a `TypeError` message to it that states why this collection does not support a `__len__` :

```
class D(C):
    def __len__(self):
        raise TypeError("Unbounded collection defines no __len__")
```